# Open File to Read from in Perl

Tags: perl, input

I just started learning Perl today. I'm on the section of file input and output. This is a very basic question, and I've been searching on the internet for a couple of hours as to what I'm doing wrong, but I can't seem to find out why. I'm sure some of you think this question should be voted down, but if I could find the answer by myself through internet searching and troubleshooting, I wouldn't be asking it here.

My question is why can't I open the file that I'm referring to in my filepath?

```
open(my $in,  "<",  "ioFile.txt")  or die "Can't open input.txt: $!";
```

The `ioFile.txt` is in the same directory as my Perl script. I've used multiple different filepaths to see which worked, and none have for me so far. I've tried using forward slashes instead of backslashes as well.

Any tips about opening this specific file or files in general in Perl would be greatly appreciated.

After Edit:

It could be permissions on the file, but I do have `read` and `write` permissions on the file, but not `full control` permissions. I'm on Windows 7 btw.

Comment: If it's in the same folder, shouldn't you be using `"./ioFile.txt"` instead? (`..` refers to previous folder in the directory tree)

Comment: if the file is in the same directory as the script, remove the `../`, so the file path appears as `"ioFile.txt"`

Comment: I've tried both those methods previously and both give the same error, `can't open input.txt: No such file or directory at C:\filepath line 303, <STDIN> line 1`, but I've removed the `../`, so no one else assumes that was the mistake causing the problem. Thanks for the input

Comment: if you do a `dir` on the command line from within the directory, do the script and the file appear? Also, your error you have `input.txt`... are you sure that's not the file in the same directory instead of `iofile.txt`?

Comment: Also, how are you running this script? What's the rest of the code? I don't think `<STDIN>` should be appearing in your `die()` output... normally that's where the script name is displayed.

Comment: Wow, when I ran `dir` it said the file name was `ioFile.txt.txt`. My stupid mistake. I changed it back to `ioFile.txt`, but I'm still not able to open the file with `open(my $in,  "<",  "ioFile.txt")  or die "Can't open input.txt: $!";`

Comment: see my previous comment

Comment: The rest of the script is really simple print and arithmetic statements. I wasn't getting any errors until I got to the File I/O part of my script. I've been going through http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html and essentially just writing down the code they have there, so I can get a hang for Perl

Comment: I checked with `DIR` and the name of the file is `ioFile.txt`

Comment: show the command line you're using to run the script. Are you in the CLI, in the same directory as the script calling it like `perl script.pl`, or are you in another directory, running `perl path\to\script.pl`? If the latter, `cd` into the directory the script is in, and then try it the former way

Comment: I'm using `perl C:\path\to\script\script.pl`

Comment: you *must* be in the directory the script is in to run it, or it will not find the file. Otherwise, change the path to the file to `"c:\\path\\to\\file\\ioFile.txt"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not running the script while you are in the directory the script and the file you want to `open` are in, then you have to specify the full path to the file:

```
open my $in, '<', 'c:\path\to\ioFile.txt' or die "Can't open input.txt: $!";
```

`perl` will look for the input file from the location you are running the script *from*, not in the directory the script is *in* (again, unless you are in that directory when you are running the script).

Comment: Don't those double backslashes look ugly. Why not switch to a single-quoted string and lose them - `'c:\path\to\ioFile.txt'`.

Comment: don't know what I was thinking. I'm almost always on nix, so I normally use forward slashes, which never need to be escaped (even on windows, so I don't know why I didn't do that anyway.